# Only the first condition applied

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python. I would like to have the following filtering, but only the first condition is applied and the other conditions are ignored. Could you tell me where am I wrong?
Here is my data:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
census_df.head()
census_df

val1=census_df['POPESTIMATE2015']
val2=census_df['POPESTIMATE2014']

def answer_one():

    return census_df[val1>val2 & (census_df['REGION']==1 | (census_df['REGION']==2) & (census_df['CTYNAME'].str.len=='Washington') ) ] 

answer_one()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to know this([Python operators precedence](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm)):

```
**          Exponentiation (raise to the power)
~ + -       Ccomplement, unary plus and minus (method names for the last two are +@ and -@)
* / % //    Multiply, divide, modulo and floor division
+ -         Addition and subtraction
>> <<       Right and left bitwise shift
&           Bitwise 'AND'td>
^ |         Bitwise exclusive `OR' and regular `OR'
<= < > >=   Comparison operators
<> == !=    Equality operators
= %= /= //= -= += *= **=    Assignment operators
is is not   Identity operators
in not in   Membership operators
not or and  Logical operators
```

For your case:

```
census_df[(val1 > val2) & ((census_df['REGION']==1) | 
                           (census_df['REGION']==2)) & 
                           (census_df['CTYNAME']=='Washington')]
```

is probably what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but why only the first condition applied and the other can not applied in my code. I think used the correct operators.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data to make it reproducible? Note your first condition needs to be closed in parenthesis.

Comment: I added my data to the question. For example here the census_df['CTYNAME'].str.len=='Washington', dose not applied.

Comment: `census_df['CTYNAME'].str.len` returns the length of strings, it's not reasonable to compare it with string such as `Washington`. Do you mean `census_df['CTYNAME']=='Washington'` or `census_df['CTYNAME'].str.len==len('Washington')`

Comment: As I execute the query it shows me all the records with other country names! Even I used census_df['CTYNAME']=='Washington', but I got the same result! :(

Comment: I mean census_df['CTYNAME']=='Washington'.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Note that `|` has lower precedence than `&`,

Comment: Worth noting that in pandas when you're doing boolean indexing based on conditions, you should always use the bitwise operators `&` and `|` and not `and` and `or`

Answer (score 1):

After putting parens around all your conditions, your code:

```
return census_df[(val1>val2) & ((census_df['REGION']==1) | (census_df['REGION']==2) & (census_df['CTYNAME'].str.len=='Washington') ) ]
```

evaluates as...

> (val1>val2)
>   
> *bitwise and*
>
> > (census_df['REGION']==2) *bitwise and* (census_df['CTYNAME'].str.len=='Washington')
> >     
> > *bitwise or*
> >     
> > (census_df['REGION']==1)

Note that you are using bitwise and (&), bitwise or (|). These have some different behaviors than boolean and, boolean or.