# Returning index of DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following DataFrame:

```
System             R    System_num
0    CO           0.8           1
1    CO           0.9           1
2    CO           1.0           1
3    CO           1.2           1
4    CO           1.4           1
5    CO           0.8           2
6    CO           0.9           2
7    CO           1.0           2
8    CO           1.2           2
9    CO           1.4           2
10   CO           0.8           3
```

I would like to return the index of the line for which R = 1.4 and System_num = 2.
I've tried by:

```
df.ix[df.System_num == 2 & df.R == 1.4].index
```

Though the error message is returning:

```
print df.ix[df.System_num == 2 & df.R == 1.4].index

     File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 834, in wrapper
        na_op(self.values, other),
      File "/apps/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 805, in na_op
        x.dtype, type(y).__name__))
    TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df.ix[(df.System_num == 2) & (df.R == 1.4)].index` you need parenthesis around the comparison also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960572/only-the-first-condition-applied/40960619#40960619).

Comment: `.ix` is [finally being deprecated!!!](https://twitter.com/wesmckinn/status/821869436797911040)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use parentheses with the `&` operator. Check out [pandas documentation for indexing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). It says:

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These
>   **must** be grouped by using parentheses.